# how to start bult-in downloader of android system with basic4android

Tags: android, download, download-manager, basic4android

I want to develop an application for the android platform  with basic4android that can download some files from my server.

How can i use android's download manager like it is used in chrome browser (thats name is downloader) ? I mean, the one when the user downloads something, a download status is shown in the notification bar.

Sorry about my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the official page the basic4android thare are some examples with download manager to prove in the framework basic4android, the best regards!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include all the necessary details in your answer rather than linking to a resource outside the site.

Comment: this link is very usefull http://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/downloadmanager-tutorial.22307/#content